# PHP FOR Iteration not iterating

Tags: php, perl, for-loop

Does anyone know why a `for` loop in PHP is not working as expected? Please check the following:

checked documentation and google about operators: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

```
<?php
    $a = "Z";
    $b = "AL";

    echo $a."<br>".$b."<br>";

for ($x = $a; $x <= $b; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
} 

while(true){
    if($a == $b)break;
    echo $a."<br>";
    $a++;

}   

?>
```

The `for` loop is not iterating, while the `while` loop is. Expected output should iterate from `Z`-`AL`, the `while` loop is doing this, but the `for` loop is not iterating.

`for` loop should follow Perl's iteration (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php), but apparently says `AL` is not greater than `Z`.

However, when converting these letters to their numeric value, the `for` loop will work as it is working with integers.

Comment: You cannot increment a _string_ variable.

Comment: Your loop doesn't iterate because `Z` is not less than or equal to `AL`.

Comment: `var_dump("Z" <= "AL");` outputs `false`...

Comment: @arkascha Sure you can. Increment `"Z"` and you get `"AA"` -- but the comparison is still done as a string, so the conditional fails.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Oh, thanks, I did not know that. Interesting. Pretty strange behavior actually...

Comment: @arkascha- Called a "Hexavegisimal" numbering system. Mainly popularized by Excel's column numbering. https://gist.github.com/pinguet62/9817978

Comment: Hexavegisimal sounds like a really terrible diet where you only get to eat six carrots a day.

Comment: even if compared as string, according to PERL's documentation Z is not greater than AL.

The for loop shouldn't compare strings and even if so, I think they should be treated according to their numeric value/code.

Comment: Why are you reading PERL's documentation? This is PHP.

Comment: PHP follows the same increment rules when treating letters to iterate, is how it determines that BC is not greather than CA for example, not by sorting. And it iterates accordingly.

Comment: _"is how it determines that BC is not greather than CA for example"_ No. There is no comparison performed when iterating. When comparisons *are* performed (like in a for loop), they're compared as strings. So `Z` increments to `AA` but `AA` is less than `Z` in a straight string comparison.

Comment: the comparison is implicit when incrementing.  the For loop should treat the variables used as variables not strings, since an increment will be made. Thanks for your answer tho, you are correct, it treats them as strings therefore it will not iterate. This behavior was corrected by getting the integer value of Z, then of AL, and placing them in a FOR loop afterwards, and it works since Z = 26 and AL = 38.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop is not iterating because the conditional fails -- 'Z' is greater than 'AL'. You can use `strnatcmp()` to accomplish what you want:

```
for ($x = $a; strnatcmp($x, $b); $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x\n";
}
```

Output:

```
The number is: Z
The number is: AA
The number is: AB
The number is: AC
The number is: AD
The number is: AE
The number is: AF
The number is: AG
The number is: AH
The number is: AI
The number is: AJ
The number is: AK
```

[EDIT] Actually, duh, that's not even necessary, just check for non-equality:

```
for ($x = $a; $x !== $b; $x++) {
```

Note this might give you an off-by one error depending on what your desired output is. Just bump $b before the loop if you want one more iteration, or use a while loop like in your example.

Comment: Hi, thanks, both are great ideas. However they will not fully cover the whole range as AL is not included as you have already stated.

The question per se can be divided in two. Why is the iteration returning FALSE, when it should return TRUE and how to make it work (But the answer to the first question will determine the answer to question number 2).

Comment: Right, so... bump $b before the loop or use an infinite loop with a break after you hit the end. Easy fix.

Comment: It should *not* return true. 'AL' sorts before 'Z'. You can make 'Z' sort before 'AL' with `strnatcmp()` but you don't need to because it's easier and cheaper to just check equivalency.

Comment: You are correct, it sorts before Z, but it shouldn't be treated as a string?, specially taking in consideration the for loop will require a variable to cicle upon, you cannot increment to a word, only to valid letters as it will be used to increment/decrement and break when the rule is met.